# Django: Can't pass parameters to Python class, name 'uid' is not defined

Tags: python, django, file, constructor, upload

I have been struggling with what seems to be a simple problem for quite a while.

I have little experience programming in Python, so I apologize for this. I have done my best to try every solution, and check this site for help.. to little avail.

I am trying to write a simple class to help me upload pairs of user-submitted files. I've wanted it to do something like this:

- Upload files *something*.txt and *somethingelse*.txt
- Process files
- Rename files to ***uniqueID***-1.txt and ***uniqueID***-2.txt
- Save files on remote server

---

So here is how I'm currently doing it for one file (since I'm doing a pair, this process can just be repeated a second time)

I currently take information from a POST request to do the following in my views.py (where newID is the uniqueID, num is the suffix of the filename):

```
newID = uuid4().hex
num = 1
upload = UploadFile()
upload.file = request.FILES['inputfile1'])
upload.save()
```

The UploadFile class is in my models.py as such:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=path_and_rename('path/', str(uid) + "_" + str(num)))
```

(where path_and_rename is a function to set the path and name of file respectively)

---

As you may notice, I never pass the newID and num to my UploadFile class. That's where I've been having trouble. I am not very familiar with Python/Django, and I have spent awhile trying to brush up. I still can't quite figure it out. I know this is a very simple problem!

As written, I get the error on execution: **name 'uid' is not defined**

I have tried creating a constructor to initialize newID and num with __init__, but I still get a similar problem. I have also tried setting the field as I did with "upload.file = ...", but that didn't work either. I've tried moving the "file" field into functions and constructors as well.

I can't really find a balance where I'm able to keep "file" in the body of class, and still have access to "self" or any fields.

How do I pass these integers into my UploadFile class?

Thank you very much for your time and help. I hope I explained my dilemma sufficiently, and I hope to figure this out soon!

Comment: Can you also give the `path_and_rename` function definition?

Comment: The fix is simple `str(uid)` is the problem and `str(name)` cause uid and name aren't defined when the code is executed.

Comment: I think the `path_and_rename` definition is unnecessary to the problem, as you've identified. Yes, `uid` and `name` are undefined, I understand that is the source of the problem. I am trying to figure out how I can/should define them.

Comment: But what are they supposed to be? You can't arbitrarily reference things and expect Python to somehow know what they are. Where are they supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Django forms.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

from .models import UploadFile


class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile


# models.py
from django.db import models

def path_to_rename(instance, fiename):
    '''Compute path to filename'''
    # define uid here
    uid = getattr(instance, '_uid', None)
    num = getattr(instance, '_num', None)
    return os.path.join(uid, filename)


class UploadFile(models.Model):
    # FileField accepts a callback that will be called when the instance is saved to get the new path
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=path_to_rename)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._uid = None
        sef._num = None
        super(UploadFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, uid=None, num=None, *args, **kwars):
        self._uid = uid
        self._num = num
        super(UploadFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import UploadFileForm

def my_view(request):
    newID = uuid4().hex
    num = 1
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            upload_file = form.save(commit=False)
            upload_file.save(newID, num)
            return redirect('where needed')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})

# template.html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<form>
```

To read about:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#filefield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Thank you for taking some time to help. I omitted most of the views.py, models.py, and template.html from my question to keep it brief, but they all look very similar to this. 

I can successfully upload a file, but my problem is with how to pass through `uid` and `num` to UploadFile.

Comment: My question is why you want to pass them? Why not declare them in the path_to_rename callback

Comment: `path_to_rename` will be called automatically to get the `pathname` and will receive the `instance` of the model and the `original_filename`. Use that plus define uid to create the path.

Comment: Okay, I could do that. But I need one of the numbers to stay consistent (uid), and the other to change (num). How do I pass that information from my views.py to the models.py and visa-versa? I need those numbers for display, processing, and the naming of the files.

Comment: The thing is that code in your view is executed when you request the page, and the one in models when you start the server.

Comment: ok. so you always want uid to be the same. Uid must be the same for this request or for all requests?

Comment: I modified my answer code. Try and see if this helps. Look at model and view changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. With some tweaks, your code works perfectly!